# How do I generate a Random.Range value once, and then use it in void Update to move? Unity, C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I want to generate a random speed and rotation value for the game that I'm (trying) to make, but if I generate the values in the Update function, it will keep generating new values every frame, but if I generate the values in the Start function, the Update function doesn't recognize it! This is the script I have now (which doesn't work):

```
    void Start()
    {
        float randomRotation = Random.Range(0, 360f);
        float randomSpeed = Random.Range(1f, 5f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, randomRotation);
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(0, randomSpeed, 0);
        pos += transform.rotation * velocity;
        transform.position = pos;
    }
```

The problem here is that the Update void does not know what randomRotation means, so it cannot do anything, however if I try `public float randomRotation` it looks like the whole script gets confused and I get a compiler error:  `error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected`
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You stored the random values in *variables* that are lost as soon as `Start` returns. Store them in a field instead

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `randomSeed` (and `randomRotation`) variable outside of the start function like so:

```
float randomRotation = 0.0f;
float randomSpeed = 0.0f;

void Start()
{
    randomRotation = Random.Range(0, 360f);
    randomSpeed = Random.Range(1f, 5f);
}

void Update()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, randomRotation);
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(0, randomSpeed, 0);
    pos += transform.rotation * velocity;
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not exactly work. The script generates the values in the Start function, but uses ``` float randomRotation;
float randomSpeed; ``` the variables outside of the function in Update, these are set to 0 so the object doesn't move...

Comment: @Ftq11 I don't really understand what you are saying. I added a default value to the variables outside of the function. Make sure you are not defining the variables inside of the `Start` function (remove the `float` before the variables inside of `Start`).

Comment: @Ftq11 it sounds like you are still declaring local variables using `float randomRotation = ....` within `Start` ... remove the additional `float` there and rather assign the already existing fields!